# PYODBC Socket Closed

Tags: python, db2, odbc, pyodbc

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v53N.jpg)I'm trying to query a database at work using PYODBC. I am able to make smaller queries no problem but when I get to some more complicated SQL it gives me a socket closed error. Any suggestions on what this could be due to?

Error : pyodbc.operationalError: (08S01) socket closed

I looked up the error and it says it's a network problem and losing connection, so I took I ran the query at my house, and it did work once but failed the second time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.